# Rails controler not passing arguments to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Probably a newbie question, but it has me stuck.

My rails program is supposed to take an origin city, destination city, and then search a database for a trip that matches the search terms. Unfortunately, I'm not sure why my controller isn't passing the arguments to the method I"m calling in the model.

In my controller I have:

```
@OneLeg = Trip.OneLeg(params[:origin], params[:destination])
```

and in my model I have:

```
def self.OneLeg(sorigin, sdestination)
  Trip.where(["origin = ? and destination = ?", sorigin, sdestination])
end
```

When I try to view the webpage I get the error:

> wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)

Not entirely sure what's causing the issue.

Thanks so much in advance for your help with this!

Comment: on which line do you get that error? share your form, probable your params doesn't have values with such keys..what do you see in logs?

Comment: the params are nil, that's why

Answer (score 0):

Probably a strong Params issue.  Try posting your Contollers private methods (tripParams or such) and we can help a bit more.

More than likely you're going to need to permit the params and access them via that params method.